# Windows 8 screen doesn't fit monitor

Tags: windows-8, screen, windows-8.1, monitor

I've just installed Windows 8.1 (my friend tells me the PC will start and shut down faster than Windows 7). I encounter some problems: the screen doesn't fit correctly There are black bars at top and bottom of the screen.

My monitor is LG E2211. I tried using the buttons on the monitor but I can't change the original ratio and It says "Digital input No access" when I choose auto.

I found this topic which has similar problem but it's only for windows 7
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/286677-33-black-bars-5850?

Also, all the games and videos is becoming a lot slower. My friend told me it's because the PC didn't recognize the graphic card. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your official graphic card's manufacturer's website and download the latest driver. I Had the same problem with mine.

Sometimes the native driver struggles to register the correct resolution or place it off screen.

Comment: All Good! Have a great day and happy gaming :)